# How do I run a for loop on multiple word files in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, text

I have 44 doc files. From each file, I need to extract the customer name and amount. I am able to this for one file using the read_document command and using the grep to extract the amount and customer name. When I do this for 44 files, I am getting an error. Not sure where I am wrong:

```
ls()
rm(list = ls())
files <- list.files("~/experiment", ".doc")
files
length(files)
for (i in length(files)){
  library(textreadr)
  read_document(files[i])
  }
```

Here is the full code that I run on one file:

```
file <- "~/customer_full_file.docx"
library(textreadr)
full_customer_file <- read_document(file, skip = 0, remove.empty = TRUE, trim = TRUE)
#checking file is read correctly
head(full_customer_file)
tail(full_customer_file)

# Extracting Name
full_customer_file <- full_customer_file[c(1,4)]
amount_extract <- grep("Amount", full_customer_file, value = T)
library(tm)
require(stringr)
amount_extract_2 <- lapply(amount_extract, stripWhitespace)
amount_extract_2 <- str_remove(marks_extract_2, "Amount")

name_extract <- grep("Customer Name and ID: ", full_customer_file, value = T)
name_extract
name_extract_2 <- lapply(name_extract, stripWhitespace)
name_extract_2 <- str_remove(name_extract_2, "Customer Name and ID: ")
name_extract_2 <- as.data.frame(name_extract_2)
names(name_extract_2)[1]  <- paste("customer_full_name")
amount_extract_2 <- as.data.frame(amount_extract_2)
names(amount_extract_2)[1] <- paste("amount")
amount_extract_2
customer_final_file <- cbind(name_extract_2, amount_extract_2)
write.table(customer_final_file, "~/customer_amount.csv", sep = ",", col.names = T, append = T)
```

Here is the code that I run on 44 file

```
ls()
rm(list = ls())
files <- list.files("~/experiment", ".doc")
files
length(files)
library(textreadr)
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  read_document(files[i])
  }
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
    > library(textreadr)
    > for (i in 1:length(files)){
    +   read_document(files[i])
    +   }

Warning messages:
1: In utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
3: In utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
4: In utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
5: In utils::unzip(file, exdir = tmp) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Comment: Couple of quick things, first you can move the library call outside the loop. Second, the for loop needs to be specified as `for (i in 1:length(files)) ` .  Can you provide any more information about the error you are getting?

Comment: (Minor point, "in general" I recommend `seq_len(length(...))` over `1:length(...)` in a situation where it is possible to have 0 elements (e.g., automated tasks). Try `1:0` to verify why.)

Comment: I do not see the `grep` function you are using for extracting information on a single file. Can you add this code ?

Comment: Here is the full code that I am running on a single file. Also, included the error that I get when I try to run this on multiple files.

Comment: Hi, I have provided the codes (including the grep code) for a single file and error above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could give you my code, which I used to analyze different word files through the sentimentr package in R. I guess you can use the same structure that I have and just change the for in function to loop the extraction for every docx.

And this is the code:

```
library(sentimentr)
folder_path <- "C:\\Users\\yourname\\Documents\\R\\"
# Get a list of all the docx files in the folder
docx_files <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = "\\.docx$", full.names = TRUE)
# Create an empty data frame to store the results
results <- data.frame(file = character(0), sentiment = numeric(0))
# Loop over the list of files
for (file in docx_files) {
# Read the docx file
sample_data <- read_docx(file)
# Extract the content and create a summary
content <- docx_summary(sample_data)
law <- content[sapply(strsplit(as.character(content$text),""),length)>5,]
# Calculate the sentiment of the summary (or in your case extraction)
sentiment <- sentiment_by(as.character(law$text))
# Add a row to the data frame with the results for this file
results <- rbind(results, data.frame(file = file, sentiment = sentiment$ave_sentiment))
}
# View the results data frame
View(results)
```

I hope that is near enough to your problem to solve it